# How to get all the projects from the Build on TFS Template?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a Default TFS build Template, and I need to be able to get all the paths of the Projects from the Solution that is being built.

I have a variable called BuildSettings that is of the type:
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings()

I thought that BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild would do it, but it only returns the path of the solution. How can I do to get the paths of all the projects inside the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DanielMann I was trying to be able to iterate through each project! But MrHinsh's solution seems to do it!

Comment: My question isn't "What do you want to do", but "Why do you want to do that?" What you want to do sounds odd, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve your end-goal. It's the XY Problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not answering the question. Most of the solutions I need to build contain project types that aren't supported by MSBuild - SSRS, SSIS, etc. I have written custom activities for a Xaml template that will handle these projects (often using Devenv.com) and our current builds list the projects rather than the solution to build. It would be useful, though, to just specify the solution in the build definition, then let the template extract the projects and select the custom task to do the build for each project. This would mean the build definition would be more robust when adding new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to Get the solution file, open it, and iterate through the projects to get that information. TF Build just passes the solution to MS Build and has no direct knowledge of the projects...

Comment: But how did you do this in a Template?

Comment: The .sln file is an open format, you will have to use code to open the file and do it yourself... I would suggest that it is not a viable solution and would ask WHY this is needed...